# How to solve ValueError raised when drawing a circle with a width value greater than its radius is pygame module?

Tags: python, pygame, border, valueerror

I am coding for a fourier transform simulation. Here I have to draw many epicycles. I have a **some values of radius which are less than 1 like: 7x10^-14, 0 etc. So, when I draw the circles and assign border width to 1 , I get a value error: width greater than radius**. If I put the border width to zero then the circle becomes filled up in color and seems very ugly. So,  please show me a way to how I can draw a cricle with a border and radius values less than 1. Here is the code:

```
radius_list = [0.0, 8.539660890638339e-15, 66.66666666666669, 3.3275832379191784e-14, ` 
1.1234667099445444e-14, 2.534379764899661e-14, 33.333333333333336, 1.018719954857117e-14, 
2.0236265985141534e-14, 2.4825216024150285e-14, 66.66666666666674, 1.5953403096630258e-13`]

run = False

while not run:
    clock.tick(fps)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            sys.exit()

    x = x_pos
    y = y_pos       
    
    for i in range(iteration):  
        
        prevx = x
        prevy = y

        frequency = freq_list[i]    
        radius = radius_list[i]
        phase = phase_list[i]
        print(radius)
            
        x+= int(radius*math.cos((frequency*time) + phase + math.pi/2))
        y+= int(radius*math.sin((frequency*time) + phase + math.pi/2))  
        
        **pygame.draw.circle(screen, white, (prevx, prevy), int(radius),1)**
```

Answer (score 0):

> [...] please show me a way to how I can draw a circle with a border and radius values less than 1

You can't. The unit of drawing in PyGame is pixels. PyGame cannot draw half a pixel. It makes no sens to draw something with a size less than 1, because PyGame can't do it:

Ensure that the minimum radius is 1:

```py
pygame.draw.circle(screen, white, (prevx, prevy), min(1, round(radius)), 1)
```

All you can do is to skip the circles with a radius less than 0.5:

```py
if radius >= 0.5;
    pygame.draw.circle(screen, white, (prevx, prevy), min(1, round(radius)), 1)
```